# How kafka consumer can deserialize different json objects?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to find a way kafka consumer to be able to read(deserialize) different json structure messages from the topic. To build some kind of abstraction may be with class id. If someone has done it I will be happy to advise.

Cheers :)

Comment: Would you be able to share some examples of the messages you're trying to consume?

Comment: I really can not show code, but it is kind of different json with some id on it to be able to distinguish how to deserialize.

Answer (score 1):

See [the Spring for Apache Kafka documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#serdes).

The `JsonDeserializer` can use type information in headers to determine which type to create during deserialization.

If the source application is also Spring, the serializer will automatically add this type information for you.

If not, you can add it a header yourself in a header named `__TypeId__` (by default).

The value can either be a fully qualified class name, or a token value, with the deserializer configured to map that value to a class name. Again, see the documentation.

If you can't set a header and need to examine the JSON to determine the type, you could start with that deserializer and make a custom version.